# Язык программирования для разработки игр

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, framework

Насколько мне известно, в gamedev сложилась традиция использовать C++. ([Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/), [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), [Unreal Engine](http://www.unrealengine.com/)). (Хотя [Quake Engine](http://www.quake-engine.com/) написан на C).

C++ это один из языков, где легко прострелить себе ногу (по большей части из-за того что он основан на Си), и чтобы писать код на нём нужно обладать большим опытом и профессионализмом. Нужно знать возможные грабли. (Отсутсвие модульной системы добавляет боли)

У меня есть подозрение, что использования C++ можно избежать.
Теперь компьютеры стали быстрее.

C++ хвалят за возможность специализации (с помощью шаблонов) методов для конкретных типов данных. (Это позволяет выполнять код без лишних вызовов, хотя это и раздувает код).

Но ведь ту же специализацию можно сделать с помощью JIT. Или, например, весь быстрый код можно записывать с помощью eDSL, с компиляцией в рантайме (к примеру с помощью [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)). Более того, этот подход может дать более быстрое выполнение чем специализированные методы C++, т.к. в рантайме доступно больше информации, и можно оптимизировать больше.

Наверняка кто-нибудь до этого уже додумался.

**Собственно вопрос**: Пишет ли кто-нибудь игры (или графические/игровые движки) не на C++? Какие есть проекты? Особенно интересуют проекты где необходимы быстрые вычисления.

Comment: [Вот][1] огромный список движков.
Можно искать по языку, лицензии и.т.д

Есть движки на asm, javascript, D, F# , и т.д и.т.п

Естественно преимуществу у С++. Но на java тоже довольно много есть.


  [1]: http://devmaster.net/devdb/engines?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=&name=&developer_name=&status=&languages_written_in_ids[]=2

Comment: Казаки и КР были написаны на Object Pascal(Delphi), есть не мало игр на C# в связке с XNA (Magicka если не ошибаюсь), Pyton (Tee Worlds).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1) O'Caml или другой из ML-family. [Бенчмарк](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/languages/ray_tracer/comparison_cpp_vs_sml.html), где кресты глотают пыль.

2) Lisp. [Warcraft 2 in 1300 lines (eDSL на Lisp)](http://pastebin.com/W4Ldv7zu).

3) Object Pascal. [Казуалка](http://hedgewars.org/) (с сервером на Haskell).

4) Любой другой, кроме крестов, если, разумеется, не стоит цель прострелить ногу всеми возможными способами и вдоволь насосаться леденца.

Comment: 1) Я верю что на Окамле можно написать нечто игровое. Но я реквестировал ссылки на проекты.

2) ДСЛ Рейфага -- это нечто страшное. Кроме того, у него кажись был довольно малый fps (16 что-ли) для всего лишь варкрафта.

Comment: Блин, но я в этих ваших персонажах не разбираюсь. А кто тогда автор DSL?

Comment: посмотрел я это сравнение, где окалм рвет кресты...
 - с++ код сразу не компилируется (видимо автор забыл, что для atoi нужно подключить инклуд cstdlib)
 - банальная замена list на vector дает 10% ускорения на ровном месте
 - окалмовский код не смог скомпилироватся. Самое интересное, что если wget'ом скачать код по ссылке download, то там совсем другой код, который при компиляции выдает кучу ошибок).
Но даже скопированный с страницы код не собирается:)
Так как я O'Calm не знаю, то судить о ошибках сложно.
И последнее, на графиках, которые приведены, не видно размерности осей.

Comment: ой как я не согласен с @Heroku … ой как не согласен…

Comment: ну если еще ожиревшую MS-ишную реализацию STL выкинуть и заменить на кокой-нибудь uSTL то возможно еще быстрее станет.

Answer (score 26):

Хотя мощности и повысились, но и уровень игрушек повысился. Если вы хотите писать игры уровня 2000 года то да, можете хоть Java использовать.

Для современных же проектов лучше всё же C++ и даже ассемблерная оптимизация.

Если не хочется изучать С++ то советую посмотреть на игровой движек Unity 3D, где написание управляющего кода возможно на JavaScript, C#, Python(Boo) а вскоре обещают и ActionScript для компилирующихся во флеш проектов.

*Кстати не стоит думать что вы пишете прямой исполняемый код на этих языках. Все скрипты написаные в редакторе будут скомпилированны. Например реализация JS в Unity почти в два раза быстрее оригинального.*

Comment: Дополню: к c++ еще можно приписать XNA Framework (точно не скажу что это, но оно относится к созданию игр), к python еще blender (вроде в нем есть какой то основной игровой движок). Насчет: хотя quake написан на c - не забывайте что c++ это надстройка на си.

Comment: XNA это MS фреймворк для создания игр. 

Очень неплохая штука, но я про неё совсем забыл, ибо не использовал никогда. 

PS:И кстати а XNA разве не C#? Дотнет жеж)

Comment: в blender'е движок соответственно 3d

Comment: XNA - шарп, но по сути это managed DirectX, так что производительность там можно вполне приличную выжать, и графику современную. В стиме многие indie-игры продающиеся написаны на XNA.

Comment: Насчет XNA не подскажу, но фреймворк точно не привязан к C#, мне казалось что в XNA C++, могу ошибаться.

Comment: XNA привязан к дотнету это точно, и я так думаю, что писать можно на любом языке поддерживаемом .NET а C++ в эти языки пока ещё входит. Про производительности никто и не спорил, XNA хорошо интегрирован в win среду плюс MS стремится сделать его промстандартом, так что скорость должна быть приличной.

Comment: Насчёт ассемблерной оптимизации: неужто в современном мире это всё ещё необходимо? Даже для требовательных игр.

Comment: Черт, я видел людей которые даже не графические приложения прогоняли через ассемблерную оптимизацию =) Так что да, оно нужно =)

Comment: Они делали это зря. В этом нет необходимости.

Comment: XNA отстой. Хотя бы потому что его нет для mono. А заставить работать .NET 3.5/4.0 + XNA 3.5/4.0 под линуксом сложно. К тому же все время с XNA проблемы даже под Windows. В зависимости от фаз луны и версии драйверов - "не найдено поддерживаемое у-во". FUUUUUUU.
Если же брать фреймворк для игр, то я рекомендую SDL. Он есть везде, он достаточно просто и еще достаточно стабилен. Используется во многих проектах, так что примеры использования тоже можно найти.
<p>
P.S. ес-но я оправдать использование XNA могу... Например, если пишете строго под .NET. С другой стороны, .NET тоже не панацея.

Answer (score 17):

Я бы разделил игровой проекта на отдельные крупные области и использовал в каждой из них приемлимые средства, выстраивая неких стек:

1. Графический движок. Тут работа с нижележащими API (OpenGL, DirectX), работа с буферами памяти, шейдерами, процедурная генерация, жесткие оптимизации. Здесь C++ вне конкуренции.
2. Игровая логика. Как правило в конечном счете это просчет взаимодействий объектов с объектами. Причем объекты вполне соответствуют объектам в традиционном ООП понимании.Действия одних объектов, могут вызывать реакции в других; объекты могут образовывать сложные иерархии. Удобно воспользоваться объектно-ориентированным языком с автоматической сборкой мусора, чтобы сосредоточиться на поведении игровой среды. Например, C#, Java, Python, Ruby.
3. Алгоритмическая база. Различные варианты AI, работа с графами и сложными структурами данных, поиски и сортировки. Задачи, типичные для функциональных языков. F#, Scala, Lisp, Haskell, OCaml, Clojure.

Разумеется, не стоит разводить зоопарк трудносовместимых сред в одном проекте. Но некоторые комбинации могут быть вполне эффективными: C++/Java/Scala, C++/C#/F#, C++/Python

Comment: > Здесь C++ вне конкуренции.

Это главный вопрос треда. Ужель вне конкуренции и иного пути нет?

Comment: @Vladimir_Gordeev выше разве что ассемблер

Comment: Тогда уж ниже )

Comment: >Ужель вне конкуренции и иного пути нет?  Есть - можно ждать , когда массив ненужных floatbuffer :) наконец-то очистит garbage collector :)

Comment: Таким достоинством как сборка мусора часто приходится жертвовать, чтобы получить нормальную производительность без пропущенных кадров. В идеале в игровом цикле выделений памяти быть не должно. Пулы объектов даже в **базовых примерах** на XNA есть.

Answer (score 16):

Лично я пишу с `XNA Game Studio + Visual Studio Express (C#`).

1. легко писать код
2. много информации в интернете
3. можно написать что-то типа такого: http://exdream.com/XnaRacingGame/
4. и т. д.

Comment: и работает только на Windows, да и .NET нужен…

Comment: Во-первых, хна протухла (последняя версия вышла 4 года назад). Во-вторых, на её замену пришёл MonoGame, написанный энтузиастами. Он со всех сторон кросс-платформенный, но для разработки в IDE до сих пор не всё дописано (нужен XNA).

Answer (score 15):

Minecraft написан на Java. можете погуглить на эту тему

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj есть немало альтернативных реализаций в том числе и на JS

Comment: > если бы на С++ написали был бы

Что бы изменилось на ваш взгляд?

Comment: @Nofate Собственно, сейчас на ваш вопрос легко ответить: насколько я слышал, конкуренты майнкрафту написаны, в том числе на плюсах и на шарпе. И таки они все рвут майнкрафт по производительности (карты можно больше и т.п.). Но мне до майнкрафта никакого дела нет, так, краем уха слышал, поэтому никаких ссылок предоставить не могу.

Answer (score 13):

[Цивилизация](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization) - движок ест-но на плюсах, а скриптование на Python

[World Of Warcraft](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Warcraft) - скриптование на Lua

Ну а небольшие и 2D игры можно писать целиком на интерпретируемых языках, используя порты движков навроде [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/).

Comment: да, и у pygame большая часть модулей на C написана

Answer (score 13):

На .Net вполне приличные игрушки можно делать, например есть игровой движок [NeoAxis Engine](http://www.neoaxis.com/ru) ну и как писали ранее XNA, Unity 3D

Comment: Более того на юнити вполне себе коммерческие многопользовательские проекты пишут.

Answer (score 13):

Для начала надо определиться с несколькими вопросами, потому что ответить на вопрос в общей форме "На каком языке писать игру?" невозможно в принципе.

Во-первых, какую игру вы собираетесь писать? Варианты ответа:

1. Игру ААА-класса, чтоб убер-графика, убер-эффекты, всё реалистичное, чтоб у игрока челюсть отваливалась от одного скриншота.
2. Серединка-наполовинку: полу-инди с полу-убер-графикой.
3. Хлам для мобилок и браузеров: геймплей — ничто, монетизация — всё!
4. Тру-инди: из графики только пикселизованные монстрики. Вся суть — геймплей!

Во-вторых, кто вы по профессии? Варианты ответа:

1. Крутейший специалист по компьютерной графике, доктор по алгебре и дискретной математике, ассемблер — ваш родной язык, шейдеры пишете с закрытыми глазами.
2. Простой смертный программист.
3. Первый раз видите компьютер вживую. Про языки программирования что-то в последний раз слышали в школе.

В-третьих, кто вы по отношению к игре?

1. Автор, владелец, вдохновитель.
2. Шестерёнка в компании.
3. Только сейчас задумались о гейм-деве.

Теперь, когда вы держите в уме ответы на эти вопросы, можно заняться разбором вариантов.

`*1*` Если вы крутейший специалист, то вы не читаете этот вопрос. Пропускаем.

`1*1` Если вы заправляете разработкой ААА-игр, то вы тоже не читаете этот вопрос.

`**2` Если вы работаете на кого-то, то выбора у вас нет. Ха-ха-ха.

`1**` Если вы хотите заниматься разработкой игр AAA-класса, то есть некоторый выбор.

`13*` Если вы простой смертный, решивший приобщиться к разработке самых дорогих игр, то выбора особо нет.

На данный момент практически все игры ААА-класса пишутся на C++, как самом подходящем для этой цели: практически все существующие, актуальные и передовые средства разработки (библиотеки, программы, инструменты) поддерживают C++; это один из немногих языков, который позволяет опускаться так низко к железу, насколько надо (ближе только C); на C++ написано огромное количество кода во многих компаниях, у него огромное наследие — пожалуй, самое огромное из всех языков на данный момент.

Для мелких фиговин, типа скриптов для управления интерфейсом, могут использоваться другие языки — менее шустрые, но которые легко обновлять и писать: Lua и прочие. Обычно они составляют не самую большую часть логики.

Или вы уже разрабатываете, или только собираетесь — выбора у вас нет, C++ надо изучать, если хотите заниматься разработкой всерьёз, а не клепать скриптики.

Есть, конечно, вероятность, что через некоторое время будет создан "убийца плюсов", но пока дела на этом фронте продвигаются неважно. Если вдруг продвинутся, то вы будете об этом знать — всё-таки событие мирового масштаба.

`22*` Если ваша игра обойдётся без самой совершенной графики, и вы умеете программировать, то у вас уже есть выбор.

Чем меньше у вас сложной логики, тем свободнее выбор языка. Если у вас тьма тьмущая сложных алгоритмов, например, в вашей игре моделируются какие-то сложные процессы, то эти алгоритмы придётся писать на C++. Как вариант, можно посмотреть в сторону функциональных языков, но это на любителя: чем больше языков в программе, тем больше сложностей, особенно когда в команде вы не один.

Если нагрузка на CPU ограничена, то вы можете воспользоваться тем фактом, что CPU — отдельно, GPU — отдельно. Если вы даже из самого медленного языка отправите на отрисовку пучок графических операций, то они отработают быстро, потому что они будут выполняться отдельно от вашего тормозного кода. Сейчас, когда компьютеры стали достаточно быстрыми, часто ресурсов хватает на все дополнительные тормоза, которые возникают из-за управляемого кода (C#, Java и т.д.).

Отдельно надо упомянуть сборку мусора: чем сложнее логика, чем вы придирчевее к частоте кадров, тем менее доступным становится это удобство. Если логика разрастётся, то с большой вероятностью может оказаться, что от сборки мусора вообще придётся отказаться и повсеместно использовать пулы и прочие подобные средства. Дело в том, что сборка мусора, какой бы быстрой она ни была, на данный момент слишком медленная, чтобы не приводить к пропущенным кадрам. Мусор, генерируемый со скорость 60 кадров в секунду, разрастается слишком быстро.

`23*` Если вы ничего толком не умеете, то писать сложные игры в качестве первой попытки не стоит. Начните с чего-нибудь попроще.

`42*` Если графика у вас относительно простая, а сложных ресурсоёмких алгоритмов нет, то ваш выбор становится очень широк.

Вы можете писать абсолютно на чём угодно! Игру можно писать на любом интерпретируемом языке, который на порядки медленнее оптимизированого кода на C++. Какая разница, если игрок не заметит?

И чем меньше у вас команда, тем более диким может быть ваш выбор. Если вы в команде единственный программист, то можно писать на любом эзотерическом языке программирования, ведь это никому не помешает, а вы получите от этого истинное удовольствие.

Если у вас есть какая-никакая команда, то лучше всё-таки считаться со мнением окружающих и не использовать языки и инструменты, про которые никто не слышал. Даже если ваша текущая команда знает их, потом может оказаться, что найти замену человеку невозможно. Используйте проверенные временем инструменты, используйте мейнстримовые языки программирования. Может, это и ухудшит производительность труда, но риск оказаться ни с чем будет заметно ниже.

`43*` Если вы не умеете программировать, то вы на распутье: вам или надо научиться программировать, или воспользоваться более простыми средствами разработки игр.

Пугаться программирования не надо. Кто знает, может, у вас скрытый талант? Есть истории успеха, когда художник, впервые увидивший код, пишет успешную игру практически в одиночку и выигрывает кучу призов.

Но есть и путь проще: движки для игр, предназначенные для непрограммистов. Там вы будете рисовать нужное вам, расставлять свойства, копировать скриптики и смотреть, как оно всё шевелится. Но чем сложнее игра, тем больше нужно кода. Подобные движки часто сильно ограничивают свободу творчества, поэтому выбирайте сами, в каком направлении лучше двигаться.

`3**` И напоследок: если вы пишете для мобилок и браузеров, то вы имеете уникальную возможность настолько же быстро упираться в аппаратные ограничения, как и игры ААА-класса (которые для мобилок существуют с точки зрения денег, но не с точки зрения результата, но это так, лирическое отступление).

Здесь ваш выбор будет сильно ограничен платформой (или платформами). Для одной платформы "родной" один язык, для другой — другой. Выбор, на чём писать кросс-платформенные игры, невелик. Писать код на управляемых языках придётся немного по-другому, уделяя пристальное внимание сборке мусора. Здесь вы будете убиваться об стенку, чтобы ваша игра нормально работала на всех устройствах.

Так как ни одна платформа не доминирует, то сразу смотрите в сторону кросс-платформенных движков и библиотек. Псевдо-ААА тоже сплошником на нём пишется, и это никого не смущает. Так как разнообразие невелико, то в трёх соснах не заблудитесь.

P.S. Я ещё не рассмотрел тьму тьмущую вещей: для какой платформы вы пишете, как выбирать движок и т.п. Считайте это общим вектором, а не инструкцией по применению.

Comment: @Abyx Если вы не видите в тексте ответа на вопросы "Пишет ли кто-нибудь игры (или графические/игровые движки) не на C++?" и "Особенно интересуют проекты где необходимы быстрые вычисления", то вам нужно внимательнее прочитать ответ. Там перечислено и кто использует, и почему использует, и как использует. Да, ответ написан не в том ключе, что и вопрос, но он включает всю необходимую информацию. А что касается списков проектов на языках, отличных от C++, то актуальные версии этих списков можно найти на сайтах движков. Эта информация устареет через год и вообще оффтопик на SO.

Comment: @Abyx "Нужны быстрые вычисления" — это абстрактное понятие. Быстрые насколько? Понятие "быстро" существует только в рамках конкретного приложения. Отсюда сортировка по первому типу: у ААА и инди разные "быстро". / Стандарт в индустрии для игр, которые упираются в железо — это плюсы. Выбирая любой другой вариант, вы кладёте или на команду, или кросс-платформенность, или ещё на что-нибудь. Потеря производительности — это не единственное, что вас остановит. / Реально выбор есть только у инди-одиночек. И чисто жанрово им упереться в железо не так просто.

Comment: Итого: вопрос не имеет смысла, что ответ и раскрывает.

Answer (score 12):

Пишу лёгкие игры (целых две штука) на `Objective C` для `iOS`. О популярности данной отрасли можете судить сами по размеру `AppStore`

Comment: Для мелких игр это более чем оправданно.

Comment: Ну obj-c-то на самом деле двоюродный брат плюсови полностью совместим с C, потомком которого является. На мой взгляд главный его плюс - развивается он в основном apple и для одной и более-менее для одного действия, а не как плюсы - куча диалектов и для всего подряд

Comment: фу-фу-фу обжектив. уж лучше плюсы

Answer (score 12):

На Haskell, скажем, вполне себе успешно пишут, например, 3DFPS [Frag](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Frag), паззл [Raincat](http://raincat.bysusanlin.com/) или платформер [Nikki and the Robots](http://joyridelabs.de/game/) (хотя в последнем физический движок взят готовый, написанный на C). Игры, учитывая их ясно некоммерческое происхождение (тот же Frag, скажем — диссертация), вполне себе приличны, так что явно не скажешь, что не написать ничего хорошего.

С другой стороны, впрочем, Кармак на QuakeCon говорил, что [со скриптовыми интерпретаторами лучше не связываться](http://www.codingthewheel.com/game-dev/john-carmack-script-interpreters-considered-harmful), и что с ActionScript, скажем, они огребли достаточно проблем. И с его опытом не поспоришь, хотя, с другой стороны, его опыт относится к достаточно конкретной игровой нише.

Answer (score 10):

Можно писать на разных языках, даже на скриптовом Lua. А движки здесь посмотреть можете всевозможные - gcup.ru

Answer (score 9):

Если вы собираетесь писать серьезные игровые движки, то выбор один это С++.

Тем более С++ не так страшен, как о нем говорят. Сейчас многие унижают С++. Называют его мертвым языком, но вы должны понимать что это в основном маркетинг таких гигантов как Microsoft и Oracle, которые пиарят свои продукты C# и Java. Фраза про выстрел в ногу не исключение. Стоить заметить, что та же Microsoft все свои разработки пишет на С++. В любом случае более богатые возможности языка С++ я всегда считал плюсом, а не минусом.

В чем основные отличия С++ от Java и С#:

1. Вам придется понять что такое указатель и ссылка. На самом деле это не сложно, если понять что такое адрес. Если сами не разберетесь, думаю на этом ресурсе вам помогут.
2. В С++ нет сборщика мусора поэтому память придется чистить в ручную с помощью delete. То есть нужно запомнить, если выделили память через new, то где-то дальше в в программе вы должны очистить ее с помощью delete.

Вот в принципе и все основные неудобства которые может вызвать С++ по сравнению с С# или Java.

Теперь поговорим почему разработчики движков не часто используют C# или Java.

Вы упомянули про JIT. Как раз JIT компиляция проблем не создает а а даже может помочь при оптимизации под конкретную архитектуру, увеличив производительность. Компилятор Clang (LLVM) как раз развивается в этом направлении.

Основным недостатком C# и Java, является сборщик мусора.

Сейчас объясню почему.

Игровой движок представляет из себя фактически бесконечный цикл, который должен выполнятся 30 раз в секунду, а лучше 60 или больше. А вот теперь представьте, что вы написали движок который выдает 30 fps. Все работает, все круто. А затем пришел сборщик мусора. Чтобы очистить память он должен остановить выполнение процесса (ну или хотя бы потока), так как сборщик не может анализировать память которая изменяется. Что выйдет из такой приостановки программы сами можете догадаться. То есть в вашем движке живет что то, что пожирает ресурсы и периодически приостанавливает выполнение вашей программы. И самое страшное вы этим практически никак не можете управлять. Согласитесь это не приемлемо, если конечно у вас ресурсов не до фига.

К еще одному недостатку языков С# или Java можно отнести большее потребление памяти, что для игр также критично.

Исходя из этого тот же С# хорош для indie игр, и не пригоден для разработки серьезных движков.

Так что использование С++ в gemedev это не традиция, это скорее необходимость, так как альтернативы нет. В любом случае С++ хороший язык, с богатыми возможностями, так что советую его изучить, если вы действительно собираетесь в будущем писать качественные движки.

Comment: > Основным недостатком C# и Java, является сборщик мусора.

А что, realtime/pauseless garbage collection назад разизобрели? Если та же Java успешно применяется, например, для [HFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-frequency_trading), то где факты, показывающие, что она действительно плоха для игр кроме старых историй времен stop-the-world GC?

Comment: То что сборщики мусора со временем стали совершеннее это факт. Теперь многие вещи GC собирают в параллельном потоке. Но все в фоне собирать невозможно. Такой способ сборки хорош в многооконных интерфейсах, но не в играх. К примеру для HFT все проблемы с нехваткой ресурсов лечатся покупкой новых серверов. Можно хоть каждому клиенту отдельный сервер поставить. И для HFT я бы тоже использовал Java. Но я же не могу купить еще Xbox 360 и сделать так чтоб у меня производительность увеличилась. Даже один параллельный поток который вы не контролируете в играх неприемлем из-за ограниченности ресурсов.

Comment: Цифр бы… Задержка выполнения типичным concurrent mark-and-sweep мусоросборщиком в Java, составляющая, AFAIK, десяток-другой миллисекунд раз в несколько минут — пренебрежимо мала. Ну просядет на время mark-фаз фреймрейт на целый 1-2 FPS'а, ну и черт-то с ним, правда же?

Опять же, например, если у кодера хватает времени, чтобы отслеживать каждый указатель и чистить память руками, то ему явно хватит времени, чтобы убедиться, что young space не будет сильно забито объектами, и пауза на initial mark-фазе будет минимальна (скажем, миллисекунда), т.к. GC будет занят только поиском в стеках. И т.д..

Comment: Сейчас многие унижают С++. Называют его мертвым языком, но вы должны понимать что это в основном маркетинг таких гигантов как Microsoft и Oracle, которые пиарят свои продукты C# и Java. 
Мертвым его никто не называет, кроме упоротых кодерков на php. Называют просто ненужным, ведь есть java/c#/%любой_другой_язык%. Это не "маркетинг", а суровая реальность. К примеру, я ненавижу C++ за кучу синтаксического оверхеда и ужаснейшие костыли, навязанные обратной совместимостью с C. В то же время C++ мне нравится за кучу предоставляемых им возможностей. Точно так же я одновременно люблю и ненавижу C#.

Comment: > Стоить заметить, что та же Microsoft все свои разработки пишет на С++. В любом случае более богатые возможности языка С++ я всегда считал плюсом, а не минусом.

Не все, но многое пишет, да. Богатые возможности - безусловно, плюс. Весь остальной трэш и ад - это огромный минус. Для C++ за все эти годы не сделали ни нормальной стандартной библиотеки, ни полноценной среды разработки.

Comment: > Вам придется понять что такое указатель и ссылка. На самом деле это не сложно, если понять что такое адрес. Если сами не разберетесь, думаю на этом ресурсе вам помогут.

Вы так говорите, будто в C# нет указателей.

Comment: Я, про C++, отмечу еще такую историю, что тот самый Skyrim когда его только релизнули был собран — тадам! — без оптимизаций. С `-O0`, да-да. Вскоре появились патчеры (см. про «TESV acceleration layer»), которые заменяли особо тормозные места и поднимали производительность на добрые 30-50% (а у некоторых, если не врут, и под 100%). Если тормозная реализация, тратившая четверть процессорного времени на бесполезные вычисления, прошла бета-тестеров и успешно шла у тысяч игроков в день релиза — о каких критичных «тормозах GC» может идти речь, когда GC уж наверняка не четверть времени отъест?

Comment: Ладно вы победили, не буду с вами спорить. Тем более данный ресурс не для этого.
Наверное это просто мировая индустрия с ума сошла и клепает игры на С++, когда есть Java. Ну у крупных издателей наверное денег куры не клюют и поэтому они могут себе позволить более дорогих С++ программистов и тратить больше времени на разработку и отладку.
А разработчики Minecraft тоже от скуки решили все на С++ переписать делая порт на XBOX 360, ну им делать наверное нечего вечерами.
Вот так бедные разработчики в gamedeve и живут, никто им про Java не расскажет. САРКАЗМ

Comment: Ну знаете, возьмите как пример цивилизацию 3.
После продолжительной игры каждый ход начинает просчитываться 2-9 минут даже на мощных процессорах.

А что там?
Средняя карта 128x128 
около 100-2000 юнитов.

Каждый ход:
Для 10-30% из них необходимо рассчитывать путь( ресурсоёмкие алгоритмы поиска пути).
ИИ что делать каждому юниту на каждом шаге маршрута.
Для городов необходимо рассчитывать связи, дороги ( ресурсоёмкие алгоритмы поиска пути).
Экономику (есть ли ресурсы на клетках).
Дипломатию(взаимоотношения государств по целому ряду моментов, в том числе при передвижении юнитов).

Comment: ------------------------
Ведение статистики по каждому ходу.
И еще куча вычислений.

Если всё это рассчитывать на языках высокого уровня то время хода составит 20-40 минут.

Comment: Простите вы наверное просто не поняли мой последний пост это был чистый сарказм.

Comment: Ну так может нужно просто вовремя чистить последнюю генерацию объектов, и все будет ок?

Comment: @andreyfomin 
Это я не вам, а drdaeman про Skyrim. 

Раз 3D, то еще не значит, что больше ресурсов будет есть.  Иногда простые с виду операции вроде транспортных, промышленных задач или множество gui менюшек пожирают больше времени чем красивый, но пустой 3D мир.

И вообще понятие игры очень растяжимое.  
То что сейчас называют геймдевом, это скорее относится к android, телефонам, приставкам, онлайн и мини играм. Вот там как раз доля С++ крайне низкая(кроме приставок).

А классическая индустрия видеоигр на PC предпочитает С++.

Comment: Ну это вы уже решили холивар развести. Спор ради спора. Я вам говорю что Minecraft переписали на С++, вы говорите что на С#. Хотя это гуглиться за пару секунд. И нетрудно выяснить что Minecraft для XBOX 360 переписали именно на С++. Вот зачем вы так делаете? Данный ресурс не место для холивара и троллинга. Еще раз повторюсь. Вы во всем правы это конечно же вся индустрия из тысяч программистов неправа или нехочет переучиваться или еще там что. В любом случае в откровенный холивар я вступать не собераюсь и больше вы от меня ответа не увидите. Удачи.

Comment: @andreyfomin, обижайтесь сколько хотите, но [minecraftwiki](http://ru.minecraftwiki.net/Xbox_360_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) утверждает что там _и_ C# с XNA _и_ C++, что дает все основания считать что C++ там, кхм, managed.

Впрочем, несомненно, аргументы про миллионы^W тысячи программистов очень конструктивно и с цифрами показывают что GC в играх никак не применим, даже если он не то что low-pause с 20ms раз в минуту а вообще pauseless.

В общем, и Вам всего хорошего.

Answer (score 6):

Специально для тех, кому не нравится вычленять информацию из ответа, а хочется голых фактов, пишу ещё один ответ.

#### TL;DR

Учите плюсы.

#### Длинная версия

Если у вас есть команда, то ваш выбор ограничен мейнстримовыми языками. Выбрать экзотический язык могут себе позволить только инди-одиночки, а реально нуждаются в нём — те, кто пишет алгоритмически сложные игры. Так как пересечение двух вышеописанных множеств пренебрежимо мало, то, вероятно, всех на самом деле интересует написание написание средненьких и инди-игр небольшой командой. Эрго, рассматриваем применимость мейнстримовых языков.

- C++. Язык по умолчанию. Абсолютный рекордсмен по производительности, по кросс-платформенности, по совместимости со всем и вся, а также обладатель самого масштабного наследия кода. Плюсы кошмарны, несмотря на тщетные попытки запрятать указатели куда подальше, а текст ошибок сделать хоть немного вменяемым. Undefined behavior и прочие радости жизни никуда за столько лет не девались. Но язык обладает преимуществами, к которым остальные языки даже не приблизились.
- Java. Язык популярен во многих сферах, в результате для него написано много библиотек, в том числе для игр. Производительность — плохая (в несколько раз медленнее плюсов на математических тестах). Возможности для оптимизации очень ограничены. Несмотря на хорошую кросс-платформенность, портирование далеко не на все актуальные платформы будет безболезненным: забудьте про XBOX, виндофоны и прочие девайсы.
- C#. Примерно на равных состязается с Java в энтерпрайзе, но сильно устапает по популярности в опен-сорсе. Изначально производительность такая же плохая, как у джавы, но возможности оптимизации значительно шире. Если при проседании производительности в джаве вам придётся переписывать критичные куски на другом языке, то в случае шарпа есть возможность уйти "на уровень ниже" в пределах языка.

  Часть игровых движков с потрохами на плюсах позволяют писать код на шарпе. Если нагрузка на CPU позволяет расходовать ресурсы впустую, то можно использовать.

  Совершаются попытки компилировать в нативный код, но это всё равно далеко не C++ по производительности: "управляемость" языка никуда не девается из-за компиляции, пусть и с компилятором на базе плюсового.
- VB.NET. Как C#, только с меньшими возможностями для оптимизации и меньшим выбором библиотек. Преимуществ над C# не имеет — ну, кому-то может нравиться синтаксис.
- JavaScript. Антирекордсмен по производительности, несмотря на попытки добавить хитроумные оптимизирующие прибамбасы в браузеры. Жабоскрипт выбирают не от хорошей жизни, особенно в геймдеве. Собственно, если вы пишете для браузеров, особо выбора нет.

  В браузерах всё медленнее минимум на порядок — не только исполнение кода, но и отрисовка графики — тормозят даже простенькие инди-игры. Как способ оптимизации никто в здравом уме и трезвой памяти этот язык использовать не будет. Из достоинств — работает везде, где есть браузер.
- Objective-C. И компиляторы, и язык — с сишными корнями. Уход на Obj-C сложно назвать уходом от страшного и ужасного си, так что выпадает из рассмотрения. Ну и Apple пытается запрятать морально устаревший язык под ковёр, выставив Swift — перспективы не лучшие (правда, только если смотреть далеко в будущее). Кросс-платформенность никакая.
- Delphi. В новых версиях заявлена кросс-платформенность, так что можно рассмотреть. К сожалению, кросс-платформенность настолько тормозная, что приложение-пример падает из-за недостатка памяти. Собственно, всё.

  Язык родственен C++, в последних версиях появились обобщённые типы и прочее, при этом в нём меньше мрака вроде undefined behavior. Однако и многих возможностей плюсов нет, а компилятор так и не приблизился по оптимизациям к плюсам.
- Python, Ruby и иже. Главные конкуренты с жабаскриптом по тормознутости. Питон, написанный на шарпе, питон, написанный на "почти питоне", и прочие подобные приблуды, пытаются выжать из языка сносную производительность, чтобы не было стыдно на фоне жабаскрипта, но до плюсов как до Луны пешком. Разумеется, как и для любого мейнстримового языка, имеется зоопарк библиотек-фреймворков, но кросс-платформенность ограничена.

#### Итог

Для "скриптовых" языков пишутся разнообразные оптимизаторы. Но динамическую типизацию никуда не выкинешь, поэтому невозможно оптимизировать код, оставив его в первозданном виде. Иногда изобретаются подмножества языка, чтобы на них писать что-то более оптимизированное, но это ломает весь кайф, что называется.

В несколько более выигрышной позиции "управляемые" языки. Совершаются попытки вроде прикручивания плюсового компилятора, прикручивания LLVM, но управляемость остаётся на месте. Ну и в случае C# и то, и другое находятся на ранних стадиях развития, поэтому говорить о результатах рано.

Строго типизированные компилируемые языки без хитрых оптимизаций все слишком родственны с плюсами, чтобы гордо заявить "я теперь не пишу на сях". Учитывая пропасть в кросс-платформенности и совместимости, переходить на них смысла нет.

Так или иначе, скомипилированный код всё равно оказывается быстрее, потому что JIT должен быть быстрым. Проект на плюсах, компилирующийся час — это нормально. Проект на другом языке, компилирующийся у игрока час — это ни в какие ворота.

На данный момент на горизонте не видать ничего, способного из мейнстримовых "несишных" языков выжать сишную производительность. Если упираетесь в CPU, и вы не один в команде, вариантов у вас нет.

Comment: Долгое время компиляции C++ — не свидетельство его крутости, а недостаток его модели модульности (унаследованной от C): header/include. На C++ вы не можете скомпилировать заранее все шаблоны (по очевидным причинам), их приходится перекомпилировать с каждым cpp-файлом.

Comment: @VladD Компиляцию не только отсутствие модульности тормозит, но да, это важный фактор.

Answer (score 5):

Для создания простенькой 2Д игры , можно учить скриптовые языки, а для красивой 3Д игр, нужно конечно знать плюсы или C#. Есть множество игровых порталов которые рассказывают о создании игр, и один из них описал **iwowa**.

Answer (score 4):

Для `managed DirectX` под дотнет есть куча фреймворков - `SharpDX, SlimDX, Tao Framework`. связка какого-то из них и `Unity3D` по идее должна дать возможность вполне себе писать движки на шарпе.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ММО, точнее не игра а на текущий момент разработка на Blitz3D+C#. В сил некоторых обстоятельств название разглашать не могу.

Comment: Ух ты., блиц3д до сих пор жив?

Answer (score 1):

Игры можно писать на каком угодно языке, к примеру для питона существует неплохой фреймворк [pyglet](http://pyglet.org/)

Если нужно что то более серьезное рекомендую [unity3d](http://unity3d.com/)

Comment: Можно использовать Game Make, в основном нацелен на 2D игры, но есть библиотеки и для 3D вариаций. Если посерьезней, то Unity 3D позволяет создавать полноценные игры как в 2D так и 3D форматах, портируя их на уйму платформ. Используется при этом Jscript и C#. Информации в сети достаточно. Модельки легко можно импортировать. Существует много Asset'ов с бесплатными сборками текстур,моделей,систем AI, и прочих скриптов. Много времени в программе этой возился, но без хорошего моделера, который сделал бы оригинальные модели ничего толком не вышло.