# На каком языке написать игру порекомендуйте

Tags: c#, delphi, разработка-игр, c++

На каком языке легче всего можно написать 3D,онлайн, многопользовательскую игру, с легкой графой ( не меньше чем у тетриса и не больше чем у Крузиса). И с сервером на php? Порекомендуйте пожалуйста.   (Не закрывайте тут спорного ни чего не может быть я прошу просто рекомендацию)

Comment: Еще раз, какой у вас движок?

Comment: Кто плюс в 1ый вопрос поставил?!

Comment: @Flammable всё будет руками с нуля. Хотел определиться с язком

Comment: @Vlmake вы издеваетесь что ли?

Comment: C# не использовать C++

Comment: @dreamchild в каком смысле

Comment: С нуля движок?

Comment: в прямом. Это форум для программистов все-таки, а не для холиваров на давным-давно изъезженные темы

Comment: Казнить нельзя помиловать? Где запятая-то должна быть?

Comment: > всё будет руками с нуля. Хотел определиться с язком

Если вы захотели написать игровой движок и у вас возникает вопрос "на каком языке писать", то вам однозначно не стоит этого делать. Просто поверьте, это действительно так. Начните с чего-нибудь сильно попроще.

Comment: Ответ с секретом

Comment: @alexlz: может, в этом как раз и ирония? :-)

Comment: Тогда (без сервера на php) простой ответ -- blender www.blender.org (сам не пробовал, только по описанию). Встроенный движок, если его не хватает -- скрипты на python'е по вкусу. Моделлер прилагается :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вообще, разработка 3D онлайн игры, независимо от выбора языка, не может быть простой по определению. ( особенно с php сервером :) )

Для того, что-бы написать такую игру, нужно проработать концепт, реализовать прототип и, только после этого, принимать окончательные (ну почти всегда окончательные :)) решения о используемых технологиях и т.д., в связи с чем рекомендую писать прототип на том языке, который вы лучше всего знаете (который вам ближе всего). И не стоит зацикливаться на графике, языке, движке и т.д., просто реализуйте минимально возможны минимум для того, что-бы в ваш прототип можно было играть и развивайте его.

Важно - как только прототип, на ваш взгляд, будет завершен, доведите его до играбельного состояния и, только если играть в него будет интересно и весело, продолжайте работу над ним, рефакторьте код, планируйте работу, в общем - вперед к мечте, если же нет, "возможно" стоит пересмотреть концепт, также, нередко, проблема в самой идее или реализации.

В общем, самое главное, что нужно понимать в начале вашего пути - в игре, на первом месте, должен быть gameplay.

И еще - подумайте хорошо, точно ли вам нужна именно 3D игра? [ссылка по теме](What to consider when deciding on 2D vs 3D for a game)

И еще, умоляю вас, ни в коем случае, не пишите движок. Вы же хотите написать игру, верно? Вот и пишите **игру**, даже если вы не хотите использовать готовые движки, не нужно пытаться все сделать переиспользуемым, красивым и т.д. иначе, с разработки игры, вы, довольно быстро, переключитесь на разработку никому не нужного движка и, с огромной долей вероятности, в скором времени, тупо потеряете интерес и забросите ваши начинания.

anyway - дорогу осилит идущий, good luck.

ps: добавьте вопросу метку gamedev

Comment: Да вообще в любом деле приветствуется такой концепт. Модная маркировка 3D тут не причём.

Comment: > И еще, умоляю вас, ни в коем случае, не пишите движок

+1

Answer (score 7):

Уважаемый ТС, вы, вероятно, не имеете ни малейшего представления о программировании как таковом. Не скажу, что это плохо (7 миллиардов жителей земли ничего не знают о программировании, и ничего), но все же когда хотите что-то сделать, то неплохо бы это самое представление иметь. 
Конечно же вы хотите все по-щучьему велению, найти этакую серебряную пулю, которая помогла бы вам ни х... не делая написать САМУЮ-КРУТУЮ-СУПЕР-ИГРУ за два дня. Так вот - таких серебряных пуль нет. Не существует таких языков, на которых можно было бы, не прилагая усилий, написать что бы то ни было стоящее, в том числе игру. Иначе толпы школоты давным-давно освоили бы это ремесло и стряпали свои супер-игры в промышленных масштабах, и стоили бы эти игры не как сейчас по 50 долларов за штуку, а по пять копеек за пучок. Но пока что этого нет, и программисты/3D-моделлеры/дизайнеры/художники/сценаристы/звукорежиссеры (кстати, заметили, как много разных людей нужно для создания игры? И это далеко не предел. Вы хоть в чем-нибудь из этого смыслите?) ценятся достаточно высоко,а условная Activision ежегодно имеет со своей Call Of Duty сотни миллионов. И в штате у них, поверьте, не самоучки, а профессионалы, чей труд оценивается очень высоко
    Здесь я не стану вам говорить того, что язык Х лучше языка У - боюсь, все равно не поймете.., да и ни к чему вам это. К тому же некто М.Перссон вообще написал свой Minecraft на Java, который никогда не рассматривался в подобном  качестве.

Из вышесказанного вытекает нижеследующее - вы не напишете игру. Тем более учитывая то, что вы еще вознамерились писать свой движок. Даже тетрис не напишете. Для этого нужна хотя бы минимальная подготовка и некий базис в соответсвующих областях, в том числе и в программировании. А услышав какое-нибудь умное слово вроде "кватернион" вы бросите эту затею и убежите играть в "Крайзис" (да-да, Крайзис, а не Крузис, уважаемый ТС)  Мне жаль (хотя, чего уж там - мне все равно)

Comment: "Молодой человек" на форумах - это уже какой-то признак дурного тона. Не пишите так, пожалуйста.

Comment: А зачем так набрасываться на молодого энтузиаста? Вполне логичный вопрос, например, есть же специально созданные языки для работы с текстом? Вполне логично предположить что может быть язык для описания игрового пространства. Наивно конечно, но рубить с плеча "Вы лузер, у Вас ничего не получится!!!"???

Comment: обычно 95% таких "энтузиастов" хотят ничего не делая получить что-то с вау-эффектом. И плодят бесчисленное поводов для флуда и холиваров. Ну это имхо.

Comment: затем, что на голом энтузиазме никуда не уедешь. А в данном случае кроме этого самого энтузиазма и нет ничего. Разве вам не кажется, что человек ищет "тот самый язык", на котором можно не  напрягаясь сделать что угодно..Так вот "не напрягаясь" - это в другую профессию, не знаю какую даже. А тут работать и учиться надо как ни прискорбно.

Comment: А Вас то почему это задевает? Они же не заставляют это делать за них? Тут вполне корректный вопрос, хотя и наивный.

Comment: > Ну это имхо.

Это ваше "имхо" стоит применять далеко не во всех случаях. Вот этот флеймовый ответ - как раз тот случай, когда имху нужно было задвинуть подальше и популярно пояснить человеку, что такое движок, что такое игра и как вообще это все делается.

Comment: >А Вас то почему это задевает?

помилуйте - мне в принципе, все равно, как я и сказал в конце своего ответа.  Если угодно, я тем самым обрисовал в общих чертах тяготы и лишения на пути разработчика. Вы полагаете, сказанное мною выше не нужно учитывать?

Comment: > Из вышесказанного вытекает нижеследующее - вы не напишете игру.

Пусть даже и не напишет. Зато, если постарается, получит массу интересного опыта. Энтузиазм нельзя подавлять.

> А услышав какое-нибудь умное слово вроде "кватернион" вы бросите эту затею

Я услышал это слово примерно в возрасте 14-15 лет. Глубоких психологических травм не получил.

Answer (score 3):

[На хэшкоде эта тема уже обмусолена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12634)

Но все же, если говорить о быстроте и простоте получения хоть какого-то результата, попробуйте Unity.

Answer (score 2):

На любом. Главное уметь изъяснятся грамотно. Вполне возможно, что писать технические статьи на английском языке легче чем на русском. Но учить английский язык ради этого - бессмысленно, умея выражать свои мысли на русском Вы сможете написать шедевр быстро и на русском. А с другой стороны, не умея выражать свои мысли, знание английского языка не поможет Вам написать что-либо внятное.